# Open multiple tabs in iTerm2 with specific directories

Tags: applescript

I would like to be able execute an AppleScript command (from a file) that will open up new tabs for specific directories.

What would be the best way to do this?

Right now I have a node.js script that I loop through each dir and pass the dir to this AppleScript file:

```
on run arg    
    set p to arg's first item
    set g to "cd " & p & "; clear; pwd"

    tell application "iTerm"
        make new terminal
        tell the current terminal
            activate current session
            launch session "Default Session"
            tell the last session to write text g
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

However, that is not doing what I like (it opens the right amount of tabs, but the last one gets everything written to it).

BONUS: if you can show me how to make the original tab active after opening all the tabs.

Comment: Better always use 'quoted form of anyFilepath' instead of 'anyFilepath'.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "iTerm"
    if exists current terminal then
        set t to current terminal
    else
        set t to make new terminal
    end if
    tell (launch session "Default Session") of t to write text "cd /etc;clear;pwd"
    tell (launch session "Default Session") of t to write text "cd /var;clear;pwd"
    activate
end tell
```